# ARP IP addresses. Am I in trouble somehow?

Tags: ip, mac-address, arp

I recently got a message from Norton Antivirus: `New network detected and saved` which confused me. I found out that I can check that with `arp -a` so I did. I noticed about 100 different IP addresses. Is this normal? Also in my second interface there are just duplicates of the IP addresses in the first interface which is odd too.

[image]

Comment: What kind of network are you connected (home, large office, school, etc)? Are those physical interfaces (Ethernet, wifi) or virtual ones, and what do you actually mean by 1st and 2nd interface specifically? Are the IP addresses from the same network i.e. same address prefix or are they completely different from each other? And do they have MAC addresses next to them or is the field blank?

Comment: Im at home. In the First two "Schnittstellen(German) there are 5 identical ip adresses. in the third "Schnittstelle" there are like 100 different ip adresses with no mac adress. Heres a screen: https://ibb.co/2SPZLZt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, some networking basics: `arp -a` will show you the ARP cache, which means both IP (layer 3) and MAC (layer 2) addresses of machines that directly can connect to your computer, as a result of an ARP message broadcast to find this association.

You left out all information about your actual network setup, but based on the information you gave, here's an informed guess:

`192.168...` is a private IP range, so that's likely your home-network address of your computer in the LAN. The three `192...` addresses are other machines in that network, including your router. The `224...` addresses and the `239...` one are multicast addresses used by various standard protocols. The `255.255.255.255` is the broadcast address.

`25...` is a globally routable address, and I've no idea why you have one of those. There is only a single other machine on that segment besides the usual multicast/broadcast, so potentially this is a point-to-point VPN, maybe to your employer's network.

The `10...` is another private IP range, so this is likely again a VPN. I'd assume you use this VPN to access the internet. I'd assume that's where are the "hundreds of IP addresses", and as you can see, they have no physical address (MAC address) in the cache.

So whenever you access the internet, your OS tries to find this address first on the initial VPN segment (probably because your netmask for the VPN is wrong). This address then shows up in this list. These are all connection **you** initiated.

So far, nothing to worry about.

Please give some information about your network setup next time you ask a networking question, then we don't have to guess. (And it's perfectly safe to fully include `192.168...` and `10...` addresses; millions of people use the same addresses, and they can't be traced to you.)

Comment: Im so thankful smart and helpful people like youu exist bc i got really worried about having hundreds of US ip adresses somehow connected to my network i paniced saved all my important files and reset my PC :3. Now theres only 192.168, three 192, a few 244, one 239 and the 255.255... adress. So its all good now thanks for your explanation.